# ArcGISでのPythonの活用

Tags: python

現在米国でGIS（地理情報システム）を勉強しているのですが、下記の課題についてどなたか助けてくださいませんでしょうか。

> Create a new script with a hard-coded geodatabase filename, that lists the feature classes it contains to the console.

ArcGIS Pro内でPythonのスクリプトを書いており、あるジオデータベース内に存在するフィーチャークラスをリストを使って表示する、という内容なのですが、ListFeatureClassというファンクションを使ってそういったプログラムを書くにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか。

下記のコードを書いてみたのですがうまく動いてくれず、何が原因かわかりません。
どなたか何かアドバイス等あればよろしくお願いいたします。

```
import os
import arcpy

# Set the workspace for ListFeatureClasses
arcpy.env.workspace = "c:/base"

# Use the ListFeatureClasses function to return a list of
#  shapefiles.
featureclasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

# Copy shapefiles to a file geodatabase
for fc in featureclasses:
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(
        fc, os.path.join("c:/base/output.gdb",
                         os.path.splitext(fc)[0]))
```

Comment: 「うまく動かない」の内容まであると嬉しいです :) たとえば、○○というエラーが出る、思っていたような挙動をしない（具体的には〜）、などなど。こちらの手元と同じ部分でお困りとは限らないためです。

Comment: 質問欄のソースコードは [ListFeatureClasses Help | ArcGIS Desktop](https://desktop.arcgis.com/ja/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/listfeatureclasses.htm#C_GUID-8A401F3B-9693-4E56-9A9E-CDE60EC912D0) だと思われますが、コメントに "Copy shapefiles to a geodatabase." と書かれています。なので、「あるジオデータベース内に存在するフィーチャークラスをリストを使って表示する」とは異なる処理(コピー処理)を行うコードに見えます。このコードではなくて、次の "ListFeatureClasses eample 1: List all feature classes in a geodatabase, including any within feature datasets." が、ご希望のコードではないでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます、明日エラーメッセージ確認します。

Comment: そうみたいですね。そちらのコード確認してみます。ありがとうございます。